# Saving the name of the uploaded file into this table on my SQL database

Tags: php, rename

This is what I am trying to accomplish.
I need the users to be able to load a picture and show it on their profile page. There is one table on my sql database named "members" with fields as follow, username, password, firstname, lastname, photo.
All fields except photo are completed on the registration form. Once users go to their profile page they will find a form to upload a picture to their profile. 
I got this code for the upload_form.php.. (code listed bellow) and another file upload_processor.php (code listed after)

This code successfully load the file into my folder uploaded_files and it renames the file to something like this... 1140732936-filename.jpg to ensure the file is unique. 
How can I get the name of 1140732936-filename.jpg saved into my "photo" field on my sql table? Is there any way? Help please....

Code for the upload_form

```
    <?php

    // filename: upload.form.php

    // first let's set some variables

    // make a note of the current working directory relative to root.
    $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '',     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // make a note of the location of the upload handler script
    $uploadHandler = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self .   'upload.processor.php';

    // set a max file size for the html upload form
    $max_file_size = 3000000; // size in bytes

    // now echo the html page
    ?>
```

Here is the html form on the same file

```
<form id="Upload" action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <h1>
        Upload form
    </h1>

    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="file">File to upload:</label>
        <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="submit">Press to...</label>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload me!">
    </p>

</form>


</body>
```

Here is the code for the file that process the form.

```
    <?php

    // filename: upload.processor.php

    // first let's set some variables

    // make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
    $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded file
    $uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';

    // make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it
    $uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'updateprofile.php';

    // make a note of the location of the success page
    $uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.success.php';

    // fieldname used within the file <input> of the HTML form
    $fieldname = 'file';

    // Now let's deal with the upload

    // possible PHP upload errors
    $errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded',
            2 => 'html form max file size exceeded',
            3 => 'file upload was only partial',
            4 => 'no file was attached');

    // check the upload form was actually submitted else print the form
    isset($_POST['submit'])
    or error('the upload form is neaded', $uploadForm);

    // check for PHP's built-in uploading errors
    ($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

    // check that the file we are working on really was the subject of an HTTP upload
    @is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

    // validation... since this is an image upload script we should run a check  
    // to make sure the uploaded file is in fact an image. Here is a simple check:
    // getimagesize() returns false if the file tested is not an image.
    @getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

    // make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is not already
    // taken... if it is already taken keep trying until we find a vacant one
    // sample filename: 1140732936-filename.jpg
    $now = time();
    while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
    {
     $now++;
    }
    // now let's move the file to its final location and allocate the new filename to it
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);

    // If you got this far, everything has worked and the file has been successfully saved.
    // We are now going to redirect the client to a success page.
    header('Location: ' . $uploadSuccess);

    // The following function is an error handler which is used
    // to output an HTML error page if the file upload fails
    function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
    {   
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
    '<html lang="en">'."\n".
    '    <head>'."\n".
    '        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-   8859-1">'."\n\n".
    '        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">'."\n\n".
    '    <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
    '    </head>'."\n\n".
    '    <body>'."\n\n".
    '    <div id="Upload">'."\n\n".
    '        <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
    '        <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
    '        <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
    '         The upload form is reloading</p>'."\n\n".
    '     </div>'."\n\n".
    '</html>';
    exit;
    } // end error handler

    ?>
```

Comment: Code for the upload_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page upload_processor.php
Add some SQL just after the image is copied to server.
I have no code therfore iam supposing you have generating image name with microtime().
Save generated image name in a variable called $variable .Then rename the image with that variable and

```
   <?php

    // filename: upload.processor.php

    // first let's set some variables

    // make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
    $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded file
    $uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';

    // make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it
    $uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'updateprofile.php';

    // make a note of the location of the success page
    $uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.success.php';

    // fieldname used within the file <input> of the HTML form
    $fieldname = 'file';

    // Now let's deal with the upload

    // possible PHP upload errors
    $errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded',
            2 => 'html form max file size exceeded',
            3 => 'file upload was only partial',
            4 => 'no file was attached');

    // check the upload form was actually submitted else print the form
    isset($_POST['submit'])
    or error('the upload form is needed', $uploadForm);

    // check for PHP's built-in uploading errors
    ($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

    // check that the file we are working on really was the subject of an HTTP upload
    @is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

    // validation... since this is an image upload script we should run a check  
    // to make sure the uploaded file is in fact an image. Here is a simple check:
    // getimagesize() returns false if the file tested is not an image.
    @getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

    // make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is not already
    // taken... if it is already taken keep trying until we find a vacant one
    // sample filename: 1140732936-filename.jpg
    $now = time();
    while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
    {
     $now++;
    }
    // now let's move the file to its final location and allocate the new filename to it
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);

    // If you got this far, everything has worked and the file has been successfully saved.
    // We are now going to redirect the client to a success page.
    //connect database
    mysql_query("update members set photo='".$uploadFilename."' where member_id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");

    header('Location: ' . $uploadSuccess);

    // The following function is an error handler which is used
    // to output an HTML error page if the file upload fails
    function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
    {   
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
    '<html lang="en">'."\n".
    '    <head>'."\n".
    '        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-   8859-1">'."\n\n".
    '        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">'."\n\n".
    '    <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
    '    </head>'."\n\n".
    '    <body>'."\n\n".
    '    <div id="Upload">'."\n\n".
    '        <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
    '        <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
    '        <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
    '         The upload form is reloading</p>'."\n\n".
    '     </div>'."\n\n".
    '</html>';
    exit;
    } // end error handler

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a million Webtecher, I just posted the code I am working on. Let's see if I can figure out how to save the image name in a variable. I'll be working on that. Hopefully I can figure it out.

Comment: I added the code,
    mysql_query("update members set photo='".$uploadFilename."' where member_id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");

The images still goes to the correct folder on the server but the name of the images is not hitting my photo column on my members table. photo remains empty :-(

I added 
     mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
     mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

Still did not work. Help please. 
thanks a million so far for your help.

Comment: are you using session_start()

Comment: echo $uploadFilename and also echo $_SESSION['id'],Note-$_SESSION['id'] will only work if you are using session to store user information,and if you are using session,then put session_start() at the top of the page

Comment: There is session_start() at the top of the page. Let me post the entire code I have on this page right before the code we reviewed to upload the photo. I am going to add it right after the correction you posted earlier. Remember this code is at the top of the page...

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I have at the top of the page

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/trusted.php'); ?>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    }
    $MM_authorizedUsers = "";
    $MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";
    // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
    function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
    // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
    $isValid = False; 

    // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set  equal to their username. 
    // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
  // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
// Parse the strings into arrays. 
$arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
$arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
// Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
} 
return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "updateprofile.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers,       $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
$MM_qsChar = "?";
$MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
$MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" .   urlencode($MM_referrer);
 header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",    $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
  {
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
 }

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?   mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
 }
}

$colname_rsuserdets = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
$colname_rsuserdets = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_trusted, $trusted);
$query_rsuserdets = sprintf("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = %s",   GetSQLValueString($colname_rsuserdets, "text"));
$rsuserdets = mysql_query($query_rsuserdets, $trusted) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsuserdets = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsuserdets);
$totalRows_rsuserdets = mysql_num_rows($rsuserdets);
?>
```